# Ideas for creating a Calendar control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I am trying to develop a calendar control as shown in the following link.

[image: http://img143.imageshack.us/i/calg.png/]

If you look into the date Nov 12th, you can see some records. The number of record will vary. So ideally the height of a row will shrink/expand based on the number of records.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

My development environment is

Windows Server 2008, Visual Studio 2008, .Net 3.5, C#

Comment: Have you thought about using an HTML table?

Comment: Yes, I think that is my only option for creating this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start here - [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).